# Adobe XD Error 3635(can not creat new document)

Tags: adobe-xd

I tried to create a new document on Adobe XD and this error showed up.

I restarted Adobe CC, reinstalled Adobe CC, restarted computer, reinstalled XD, used the cleaning tool ETC but nothing works.

How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to the file menu choose to save the file as a local document ad then create the artboard u want.

the problem is XD trying to save the document automatically to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to save XD files as a specific version,  XD file it is auto-upgraded and can no longer be opened in previous versions. Please update the xd with the latest version and try to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow any of these procedures to troubleshoot the issue:

- setup creative cloud
- Update Creative Cloud Sync
- setup adobe xd from creative cloud
- restart system

I had this issue too and solve with **uninstall adobe xd and setup from creative cloud.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Installed Creative Cloud and it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny but all you have to do is to log out of your adobe account, restart your system and open adobe xd.

Have Fun.

Answer (score -1):

I solved by logging out and then restarting the app.